# C# MVC 5, EF 6, Duplicates record writeout to SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We have an application that creates a tote, then creates batches within the tote depending on some user input.  We have found that there are random times where the insert record into the database for batches will create a duplicate record within .01 seconds of the first record.

This is the code we use to insert the batch record:

```
batch.Date = DateTime.Now;
batch.User = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
batch.Active = true;
batch.Tote = tote;
database.Batches.Add(batch);
database.SaveChanges();
```

This is the records we see from time to time:

```
1436    2016-06-14 12:41:28.617 Shipment    26  False   Part123 822 NULL

1435    2016-06-14 12:41:28.600 Shipment    26  True    Part123 822 NULL

1434    2016-06-14 12:40:38.520 Shipment    4   False   Part123 822 NULL
```

Note:  Notice the timestamp of the records have occured within .017 seconds.  The middle record is true because once all parts are scanned into said batch, we mark them as complete.

Has anyone else ran into this problem?  I am not sure if it is a network related problem, EF6, or SQL.  Any input is appreciated!

View Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.ToteID" id="toteID" />
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>New Small Lot</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartNum, htmlAttributes: new {    @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartNum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "", onkeydown = "RemoveDollarSign(this);RemoveCreateBatchPartIdentifier(this)" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartNum, "", new {  @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class  = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "", onkeydown ="RemoveQuantityIdentifier(this);TabtoSubmit(this)"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

JavaScript:

```
function RemoveCreateBatchPartIdentifier(i) {
    i.value = i.value.replace(/^[Pp]/, '');
};
function RemoveQuantityIdentifier(i) {
    i.value = i.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
};
function RemoveDollarSign(i) {
    i.value = i.value.replace(/[$]/g, ' ');
};
function TabtoSubmit(i) {
    if (event.which == '9')
    {
        i.form.submit();
    }
```

Comment: You should show a bit more of how you insert multiple records. The insert code for one record doesn't give many clues.

Comment: show your View code. Are you sending data to server via ajax? Cause those things can multiple input

Comment: Your Controller Code is good. You may have problem on Client Side.

Comment: @GertArnold We don't try to insert multiple records.  The above code is the only code we have in our solution to insert a new batch.  This should only be 1 record at a time.  We also have checks in place to not allow a new batch until the current batch is complete.

Comment: @MRebati I have updated the post with the viewcode and javascript.  Note that the javascript is there because our operators use handscanners for input.  Depending on the brand/model, the input method could change.  We ended up allowing any tab, carriage return, or enter function on the last input box to submit the form.  This works about 95% of the time, but we are seeing some problems where the same record just inputs twice almost instantly.

Comment: @MRebati  I will take a look on the client side as well.  We have had this occur on multiple PCs with different handscanners but there may be a common ground between them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was self resolved after server updates/restart.  As much as I don't like this as an answer, it did go away with a simple server update or restart.  For anyone looking at this in the near future, all other factors remained consistent.